# How to prevent getExternalFilesDir (String type) from creating directory

Tags: android, file, external, file-security

When i tried to get path from getExternalFilesDir(String type), the directory returned here will be automatically created.
How to prevent this scenario.
Please help me out ??

Comment: Question has incomplete information. Please add code snippet etc and more information.

Answer (score 0):

> When i tried to get path from getExternalFilesDir(String type), the directory returned here will be automatically created.

That's correct.

> How to prevent getExternalFilesDir (String type) from creating directory

You can't.

> How to prevent this scenario. Please help me out ??

I don't know of any good reason to try to prevent this from happening. Thus, I suggest that you reconsider your reasoning. Anyway, if you insist on preventing this scenario you'll have to:

1. Manually determine the path of the external files directory for your app and supplied type. You can check how Android does this based on the [source code of `getExternalFilesDir`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#1027). Please note that the linked source code is from the Android 5.0.0_r2 tag. I don't know if and what is different on other versions.
2. Manually check if this directory exists. You can use the [`File`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) class for this.
3. Act accordingly, e.g., by not doing whatever you would do if the directory existed when it in fact does not.